# Modular software possible or not recommended?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, modularity

I'm coding a ERP software and I'm a big fan of modularity. However, I fear at one point it's no more useful. I have the following problem:

1. I could build one function, let's say `Customer::remove()`, which
   contains code from `Order::remove()`.
2. Or I could create
   `Customer::remove()` which then access `Order::remove()`

Is it worth to use version 2 with this lot of overhead? I will need to create a new Object of type Order, build up a new connection in a thread, make a new transaction and return the result back from `Order::remove()` to `Customer::remove()` and analyse for possible errors.

edit: `Customer::remove()` and `Order::remove()` are just database communication Objects, they doesn't contain any Data. They are used to query the database specific for getting infos about customers or orders.

Comment: `Customer.Order.Remove()` would make sense. `Customer.Remove()` to delete an order would not. Abstraction, Modularity, Encapsulation, and Hierarchy are all of equal value.

Comment: It isn't quite clear why `Customer::remove()` needs to have anything to do with `Order::remove()`. Perhaps you want to remove outstanding orders from that customer, but this doesn't require you to create a new order. If you find the need to share code like that, chances are your classes are not designed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. What do you mean with customer.order.remove. The Customer object doesn't contains orders. They can be queried by `Order::get_all()`. It's more like a Database communicator class, less a Object.